# Rundeck display options dynamically

Tags: rundeck

I am using Rundeck for basic API calls periodically or manually. As of now, I have a lot of options the user has to provide, but most of them remains empty.

In fact, some of them depends on a previous one (e.g do you want X ? Then provide Y). Is there a way to display some options only if another has a given value ?

I would like not to create two different jobs but to keep only one.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One possible way is with [Cascading Remote Options](http://rundeck.org/2.0.0/manual/job-options.html)

> This provides a mechanism for declaring hierarchical or dependent sets of option values.